# jQuery is included twice in Rails application on Heroku

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

My question is similar to some other questions here which still didn't provide an answer for my situation

I am including jQuery gem in my app in Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

And in application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
...
//= require_tree .
```

My development.rb has

```
# Do not compress assets
config.assets.compress = false
# Expands the lines which load the assets
config.assets.debug = true
```

My assets are not precompiled, there is no public/assets.
Everything is running great locally. But when I push to heroku I get different application.js file included on the page. Instead of being a manifest file it has minified version of jQuery. Therefore I get jQuery included twice. Here is how source of my page looks like:

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And when I click on `/assets/application.js?body=1` I see minified jQuery. When I run my app locally and click on `/assets/application.js?body=1` I just see the manifest.
I tried to add to development.rb

```
 config.serve_static_assets = false
```

It didn't help. I also cleared assets and cache multiple times.
The only thing that works for me is setting

```
config.assets.debug = false
```

But I would like to know if there is any other option that won't affect debugging.

Comment: When you deploy to Heroku, your app will use the `production.rb` config and not the `development.rb`.

Comment: We have multiple environments for the same app on Heroku. I didn't set it up originally but I am pretty sure app runs in development mode. In the log I see `Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e development -p 59152`

Comment: Hmm.. that is probably not the preferred way to set that up - if you type heroku config you'll see your RAILS_ENV and RACK_ENV vars which will say 'development/production/staging/test' etc..
Then in your Procfile, you can edit the line for your web process to say `web: bundle exec thin start -p $PORT` and it will use the RAILS/RACK_ENV to determine which environment to run in.

Comment: It does say development. Not sure why, but it is set up in a way that all developers push to development and there is one person who pushes from development on heroku to production. I am confused myself)) But it worked for us all the way up until now. Btw production is working fine.

Comment: So are the servers that are having this issue not production servers? They are like... staging servers?

Comment: Yeah on production all assets are served precompiled. Basically we have development environment on heroku to share code before pushing it to staging/production.

Answer (score 1):

I removed this line

```
//= require_tree .
```

and creating a sub folder in javascripts and then moved all js files in javascript directory to that subfolder except **application.js**

and wrote this line

```
//= require_tree ./sub_folder_name
```

It's awsome and working.

**One Important thing to Note:**

This may cause to you as you are including a same file twice one manually by **javascript_include_tag**  and other by application.js. First confirm that if this is the case you have to include it once.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar) on heroku regarding precompiling your assets. When you push to heroku do you see any error messages around the section that says:

```
-----> Preparing Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
```

?

Comment: Nope. I see `rake assets:precompile` and then I see how long it took to precompile, no errors. `Asset precompilation completed (62.74s)
`

Answer (score 0):

Development and Production and supposed to be different (/app/assets and not minified in development, public/assets and minified in production.

As for the double-include, if your production web served page has both, I would check your app for pages like application.html.erb to see if if it's defined there.  If so, remove it.